# calculate winning percentage with a tie

Tags: nfl

How does the nfl calculate the Cincinati Bengals winning percentage with a 10-4-1 record as .700?

I did the math with 14 and 15 games played and my numbers don't add up to their numbers.

Comment: This [answer](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/1938) to a related, but different question may help...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NFL standings: 8-6-2 team vs 9-7-0 team?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1937/nfl-standings-8-6-2-team-vs-9-7-0-team)

Answer (score 13):

Ties are counted as half wins. So 10.5/15 = .7

Credit to [Peter King's MMQB](http://mmqb.si.com/2014/12/22/a-repeat-possibility/5/) this week for pointing out the half win for a tie rule.

Comment: +1. You could also have taken 0.7*15 to give the number of wins as 10.5 and with a bit of analysis realised that the tie was half a win.